# Como criar o widget "Postagens relacionadas" para o Blogger?

Tags: html, blogger

Quero criar um widget de postagens relacionadas no meu Blogger sem usar o widget [LinkWithin](http://www.linkwithin.com), já adicionei os códigos no CSS e HTML corretamente, porém não aparece o elemento quando salvo, não sei porque.

Alguém sabe de como eu faço os códigos para postagens relacionadas no blogger com imagens e que ela apareça abaixo do rodapé das páginas de postagens e não na página principal.

Um exemplo de postagem:

[image]

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, poderia dar mais detalhes.

Comment: Andei procurando na internet e achei um site que pode ajudar você com esta pergunta e pode te ajudar futuramente com seu Blogger. [Posts Relacionados com Efeito Hover no Blogger](http://www.prodeveloper.com.br/2014/08/nova-versao-posts-relacionados-com.html) Recomendo que leia o [Como fazer uma boa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)